# @lizmap_user registration

Tags: qgis, postgis, lizmap

I have a problem with @lizmap_user.
QGIS Server 3.26.3 Web Client Lizmap 3.5.7. PostgreSQL: 14.5 (Debian 14.5-1.pgdg110+1)
I wanted to enable the registration of lizmap users who edit or create new records, so inside the table I created a liz_user field, in QGIS in the form layout I set as default value @lizmap_user and I selected Apply default value on update.

[image]

When users log in if they create a new record the @lizmap_user is correctly registered, instead in case of modification the user field remains empty:

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Expressions for default value are working fine for **feature creation** but it's not supported for **feature update**.

For now, the only way is to use Javascript by reading "Send current login user-ID" in the documentation to autofill a field with Javascript code.
https://docs.lizmap.com/current/en/publish/customization/javascript.html

Maybe you should contact the dev team.

Comment: Ok thanks and sorry for the delay